# Is Excel Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Insert broken on Excel 2007?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2003

I've got this piece of code I've been using Excel 2003 which mimics a solution given on the Microsoft website from a while back. How to add more than 255 characters to a shape's text frame:

```
For i = 0 To Int(Len(myTxt) / 255)
    .Characters(.Characters.Count + 1).Insert Mid(myTxt, (i * 255) + 1, 255)
Next i
```

This just doesn't work under Excel 2007. There are two problems.

1. Insert can't insert at the end of the field, it has insert at an existing character. So `.Characters(.Character.Count).Insert` will work, even though it's not what I want to do.
2. It's operating as an overwrite, not an insert. Wherever I apply Insert it overwrites the existing characters. So an Insert at `(.Character.Count)` will delete the final character.

Now I've built in logic to operate differently depending on the version of Excel you're using. But I couldn't find anything relating to this issue. Is it a known bug? Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

(On a related note, I cannot set `.Characters(x,y).Font.Underline` = True either.)

**EDIT** In my particular example, the code above is contained with something like `With myWorksheet.Shapes(1)` where the shape is a text box. It already has text inside it and I need to append `myTxt` (a `string` longer than 255 characters) to it. This code worked without problem on Excel 2003. I've seen this problem referred to elsewhere, but looking for a formal statement on it from Stack Overflow...

Comment: Could you add the With block this is part of? And the declaration of the object? Would help.

Comment: @downwitch Added details to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, your code works in 2003 but fails in 2007. What's surprising to me, though, is that it works at all. Trying to reference "one more" character in the `.Characters` collection *should* throw an error--and if you break up your line above, as I think you're pointing out in point 1, you'll see that it's specifically `.Characters(.Characters.Count + 1)` that does. It's not the method that fails, it's the non-existent member, which seems right to me.

Here's code that does what you want in both 2003 and 2007.

```
Public Sub Loop_InsertTest()

    Dim MyWks   As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim MyTxt   As Shape
    Dim MyFrme  As TextFrame
    Dim i       As Long

    Const StartText As String = "This is a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, " _
                              & "very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, " _
                              & "very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, long piece of text."
    Const MaxIterations As Long = 1000

    Debug.Print Len(StartText)

    Set MyWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set MyTxt = MyWks.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 10, 1000, 1000)
    Set MyFrme = MyTxt.TextFrame

    'Debug.Print TypeName(MyTxt), MyTxt.Name'
    MyFrme.Characters.Text = StartText
    MyFrme.AutoSize = True

    For i = 1 To MaxIterations
        Insert_ThisText MyFrme, " Now it's even longer."
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub Insert_ThisText(pFrme As TextFrame, _
                            pstrText As String)
    Dim strRight    As String
    Dim i           As Long

    With pFrme
        For i = 0 To Int(Len(pstrText) / 254)
            strRight = .Characters(.Characters.Count).Text
            .Characters(.Characters.Count).Insert strRight & Mid(pstrText, (i * 254) + 1, 254)
            'Debug.Print Len(pstrText), .Characters.Count'
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Downwitch, just tested, it does work indeed. I already had a solution which was explicitly checking the Excel version but this is nice too. My original code was based on a KB article from Microsoft themselves thus I was put out it no longer worked in 2007: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105416

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved me!  I was having the exact same problem as Joel, and couldn't see an obvious solution.  And your comments about the `non-existent member` being the culprit is spot on.  Oddly enough, my code, which was very similar to Joel's, was taken from [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213841), so I wasn't expecting any problem in that area.